# One Signal Push Notification?

Tags: android

I have made movie review app on android.Users create an account with firebase authentication and review movies and rate them.Admin of app can add new movies.
My question is how can I(admin) send a notification to all users (of firebase) whenever I added a new movie?And I want to use one signal push notification.
Please Help me.

Answer (score 0):

Using `Tags` its possible to send the notification to all users.

1.Primarily you have create a channel eg: `allusers` from mobile end need to register

```
JSONObject tags = new JSONObject();
tags.put("allusers", "1");
OneSignal.sendTags(tags);
```

2.From server end who are all registered in the tag `allusers=1` ..Notification will send to all the users

Sending Push from serverside
https://documentation.onesignal.com/reference#create-notification